Open source alternative tool for PDF parsing like llmsherpa, LlamaParse that can run locally
I needed tools for better PDF parsing (the ability to parse tables properly) for an RAG application.
Currently, I am using LlamaParse for parsing the pdf document to markdown but it's not a self-hosted service, and I need something self-hosted as I am working with confidential data. I also tried Llmsherpa but the results were nowhere close to LlamaParse at various points like extracting some complex tabular structures.
Are there any other open-source tools I can use for PDF parsing that can handle tables and sections easily? The documents that I need to parse have some tables that are complex to read, and the RAG application performance relies on context extracted by PDF.
I also came across unstructured.io for PDF parsing but have not tried it yet will be checking it next. One thing I would like to ask before investing time in setting up an environment locally. In Official Documentation of Unstructured.io setting up unstructured.io locally on Windows will add additional challenges, so has anyone tried it locally and is it completely open if I set its environment locally will it mean all functionalities will be performed on my local machine or not?
Are there other ways to solve this problem that I might have missed?

Also searching for the same thing as you are, but as far as I can see nothing opensource is available. Because of the data confidentiality LlamaParse is also not an option for me.
As far as I can see you can either:

ignore all images in PDFs for RAG as if they do not exist,
there are libraries that can get you images from PDF page as separate objects, but handling them manually and joining them back in the document is not quite easy
render each whole page to one big image and then OCR this large image

I hope LlamaParse wil go opensource one day.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
